# python - how to merge duplicate row in one cell not combining other column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, merge

[image]

there is option available of merging duplicate row they affect in other column also.
PFA in that merging duplicate column in one cell not affect other column
please answer me how do i using python

thank you in advance

Comment: You should use [groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html). In this case if we consider table shown above as df, simply do something like `df.groupby(['Date','Name']).sum()`

Comment: What exactly isn't working? :-) Can you provide at least some working data & outputs maybe?

Comment: @DanailPetrov  thank you but its not working it merging sale column value  also I want the sale column will be keep as before.

Comment: I think you should improve on your question. Please provide at least some minimal data that could be used as well as the exact expected result. I'm afraid I don't quite understand the exact requirement here..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should improve your question, but here is what I made out of it:

```
>>> my_data = {0: {'Date': 'Monday', 'Name': 'Lucy', 'Sale Price': 1371},
     ...:  1: {'Date': 'Monday', 'Name': 'Jone', 'Sale Price': 2269},
     ...:  2: {'Date': 'Monday', 'Name': 'Emily', 'Sale Price': 4337},
     ...:  3: {'Date': 'Tuesday', 'Name': 'Steven', 'Sale Price': 4755},
     ...:  4: {'Date': 'Tuesday', 'Name': 'Jone', 'Sale Price': 3493},
     ...:  5: {'Date': 'Tuesday', 'Name': 'Lucy', 'Sale Price': 4664},
     ...:  6: {'Date': 'Tuesday', 'Name': 'Emily', 'Sale Price': 2358},
     ...:  7: {'Date': 'Tuesday', 'Name': 'Ruby', 'Sale Price': 2337},
     ...:  8: {'Date': 'Wednesday', 'Name': 'Nicol', 'Sale Price': 1256},
     ...:  9: {'Date': 'Wednesday', 'Name': 'Steven', 'Sale Price': 4706},
     ...:  10: {'Date': 'Wednesday', 'Name': 'Jone', 'Sale Price': 3351}}


>>> df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(my_data, orient='index')

>>> df
         Date    Name  Sale Price
0      Monday    Lucy        1371
1      Monday    Jone        2269
2      Monday   Emily        4337
3     Tuesday  Steven        4755
4     Tuesday    Jone        3493
5     Tuesday    Lucy        4664
6     Tuesday   Emily        2358
7     Tuesday    Ruby        2337
8   Wednesday   Nicol        1256
9   Wednesday  Steven        4706
10  Wednesday    Jone        3351

>>> df.groupby(['Date','Name']).sum()

                  Sale Price
Date      Name
Monday    Emily         4337
          Jone          2269
          Lucy          1371
Tuesday   Emily         2358
          Jone          3493
          Lucy          4664
          Ruby          2337
          Steven        4755
Wednesday Jone          3351
          Nicol         1256
          Steven        4706
```

Comment: thank you @Danail Petrov , Its solved my problem, but when i am trying to save in csv file it look like previous one. is there have any solution it will save in excel like groupby output? .... sorry for improper language